# After clicking on a tag focus should go to center of a redirected page without using #id as it is not working here

Tags: html

After clicking on a tag focus should go to center of a redirected page without using #id as it is not working here

I need to do with scrolltop

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: share you code so we can see why it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use it like :

```
document.querySelector('.orange').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

please refer the link http://jsbin.com/bivexesone/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: $('.video-link').click(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(".step-cont").offset().top
    }, 1000); 
  });